# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. LSTM Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I know multiple similar problems have been posted on the forum already, but I couldn't derive the solution from them... Anyway here is my problem:

I have an Pandas DataFrame of shape (10240, 3). The first two columns contain numeric values, while the third and last column holds labels for each row.

```html
# Selecting and reshaping the X_train set
X_train=df.loc[0:8191,df.columns != 'Label']
X_train=X_train.values.reshape([1, 8192, 2])

# Selecting and converting to categorical y_train
temp = df['Label']
y_train = temp[0:8192]
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes = 5)

# Selecting and reshaping X_test
X_test = df.loc[8192:10240,df.columns != 'Label']
X_test = X_test.values.reshape([1, 2048, 2])

# Selecting and coverting to categorical y_test
y_test = temp[8192:10240]
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes = 5)
```

Next, I try to insert the data with 5 different classes in my LSTM model, which looks the following:

```html
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape = (8192, 2), return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(50)))
model.add(GlobalAvgPool1D())
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
```

```html
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), batch_size = 64, epochs = 40)
```

Upon compiling I then get the following error: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 8192 target samples.

I checked whether the shapes of the different sets match up, and to my best of knowledge they do. Furthermore I think the input follows the [sample, timesteps, feature] "rule of thumb". And also the batch size seems to be ok. Anyhone has any idea how to get the input to work?

I'm running Python 3.x and Keras version 2.2.2

Comment: Remember that SO is _not_ a forum, so you are encouraged to tell us what other Q&A you researched, and why those do not apply.

Comment: I researched the other 3 questions I found regarding this error, but neither of the three solutions worked in solving my problem. All Questions I consulted were having an error due to misalignment of validation sets, or due to different shape sized on X_train sets which I believe is not the case here.

Comment: @Onraj LSTM takes a sequence as input so if you are sure that each of your samples (i.e. each row in the dataframe) is a sequence (column 1  and then column 2), then just reshape the `X_train` to make it have a shape of `(n_samples, n_timesteps or seq_length, n_features)` which in your case would be `X_train = X_train.reshape((8192, 2, 1))`. And also change the input shape of LSTM layer to `(2,1)`. However, I suspect that using a Dense layer instead of a LSTM layer would be better.

Comment: @Onraj _what_ other questions? You should say which Q&A you found and why it did not help. What makes your specific case unique? The idea is to keep others from duplicating your work.